# Angular-tree-ui JSON Data with $http

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-directive

I'm currently been using the angular-tree-ui component, which is a nice little component that allows nesting of hierarchical data with drag and drop support.

All has been going well until I started to pull the data from Asp.Net Web Api.

Originally the data is set as in angularjs:

```
var results = [{"id":1,"productName":"Test","nodes":[]}];
```

Which works fine.

But as soon as I use $http to connect to the Asp.Net Web Api which returns:

```
{"id":1,"productName":"Test","nodes":[]}
```

... the angular-tree-ui component complains with multiple errors.

```
"Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined"
```

Why does it work with the manual creation of JSON but not with the JSON returned from the Asp.Net Web API?

Comment: You realize the first result set is an array and the second is an object?

Comment: The JSON that was been returned from the Asp.Net Web Api wasn't just {"id":1,"productName":"Test","nodes":[]} but it was also returning the headers in the JSON aswell. I only noticed after using {{data|json}}